# Is convergence to a local minima more likely with transfer learning?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, generative-adversarial-networks, transfer-learning

While doing transfer learning where my two problems are face-generation and car-generation is it likely that, if I use the weights of one problem as the initialization of the weights for the other problem, the model will converge to a local minima? In any problem is it better to train from scratch over transfer learning? (especially for GAN training?)